# Проблема с установкой Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

("Симптома", с которым я столкнулся нет на сайте Microsoft, на который предлагают перейти для решения проблемы)

Столкнулся с проблемой установки Visual Studio Community 2015. Скриншоты проблемы:

[image]
[image][image]

Последняя строка в логе:

> [1238:0330][2016-11-08T19:34:21]i399: Apply complete, result:
>   0x80070673, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

[dd_vs_community_20161108192259.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1LJ6X0ILrxoOHZfUzBSa2lQRTg/view) — логи, которые выдала студия Visual Studio;

[vslogs.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1LJ6X0ILrxoeVNIS2RHaURweFE) — логи, которая собрала программа Collect.

(прога collect отсюда https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/3039361#bookmark-furtherhelp)

Я ранее устанавливал Visual Studio Community 2015, но потом удалял, после повторной установки не могу установить её снова, хоть чистил кэш CCleaner'ом, Uninstal tool'ом удалял всё связанное с Visual Studio, что видел, проводил поиск по компьютеру и делал то же самое, а после того как всё, что видел — удалил, пытался установить снова — результат тот же.

Есть ли способ решения моей проблемы, **не прибегая к откату Windows до заводских настроек**?

(с Visual Studio 2012, 2013 точно такие же проблемы)

Comment: Верни ссылки в кликабельный вид.

Comment: Поставить свежую версию студии не пробовал?

Comment: как только делаю кликабельными запрещает постить, потому что репутация < 10 и только одну могу делать кликабельной

Comment: Я и пробовал ставить 2015, самую последнюю(или есть новее?)

Comment: Ну на скриншоте же Update 1 с пометкой `deprecated`. Вроде, update 3 последний?

Comment: У моей знакомой была такая проблема . Она не правильно удалила и остались файлы которые мешали установке новой Visual. Выход она нашла откат винды . Но как по мне это немного жёстко

Comment: я качал с update 3, но та же ошибка была
и даже когда с update 3 качаю, оно высвечивает update 1 первым элементом установки

Comment: Пробовали реестр CCLeaner' ом почистить? Была похожая беда при установке, только на более старых версиях. После чистки реестра от хлама всё заработало.

Comment: не помогло, пробовал

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, не все деинсталяторы видят остатки от студии, "больше" остальных удаляет Revo, но это на мой взгляд. Попадал в такую же ситуацию, откат системы, не то, что требуется, это крайние меры. Попробуйте скачать и почистить, и к слову сейчас доступна VSC 2017, после чистки рискните получить лицензию на Imagine

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте скачать какую-нибудь утилиту для удаления программ и удали все остатки от старой Visual Studio. - это первый вариант. Н-р [unistall tool](https://www.crystalidea.com/ru/uninstall-tool)

Второй вариант - откатить виндоус, если есть архивирование.